# Which probability is greater, given minimal info

Tags: probability, random-variables

which probability is greater, given that $X$ and $Y$ are independant, positive random variables? There is also the option that it's impossible to know as we don't have enough information. I'd appreciate if someone could explain to me which option is correct and why.

Thank you
$$P(X>2)*P(Y>2)$$
$$or$$
$$P(X+Y>4)$$

Comment: Which region is larger, $(X>2)\land(Y>2)$ or $(X+Y>4)$? (Let's assume that infinities are comparable for the moment)

Comment: Oh, in case you don't know, $\land$ means "and".

Comment: First, what information does independence of $X$ and $Y$ give you for the first expression? Then, how do these two events compare to one another?

Comment: To follow up on @KennyLau's point, draw graphs of the regions $\{x>2\}\cap \{y>2\}$ and $\{x+y>4\}$. You'll see an immediate relation between these two regions (perhaps one is contained in the other?). Interpreting independence of $X$, $Y$ should finish the question.

Answer (score 2):

By independence of $X$ and $Y$ we have $P(X>2) * P(Y>2) = P(X > 2 \wedge Y>2)$.

Now let $A$ be the event $X>2 \wedge Y>2$ and $B$ the event $X+Y>4$.
It is clear that if we have $A$ then we have $B$. The converse however is not true :
$$
A \Rightarrow B \\
B \nRightarrow A
$$
Therefore $P(B) \geq P(A) \Longleftrightarrow P(X+Y>4) \geq P(X>2) * P(Y>2)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Comment.*  As an example, suppose $X, Y \sim Exp(rate=1)$ independently.
Computation and plot in R for 30,000 simulated realizations.
Based on hint by @NicholasStull. (Also, illustrates subsequent
answer by @Zubzub.)

```
 x = rexp(30000); y = rexp(30000)
 mean(x > 2)*mean(y > 2)
 ## 0.01812118  # Aprx P(X > 2)*P(Y > 2)
 mean(x + y > 4)
 ## 0.08953333  # Aprx P(X + Y > 4)
 plot(x,y, pch=".")
 abline(h = 2, col="red")
 abline(v = 2, col="red")
 points(x[x+y > 4], y[x+y > 4], pch=".", col="blue")
 abline(a = 4, b = -1, col="purple", lwd=2)
```

Approximations have about 2 place accuracy. Exact
computations below. In R, `pexp` is the CDF of $Exp(rate=1).$
Also $X + Y \sim Gamma(shape=2, rate=1).$

```
 (1 - pexp(2, 1))^2
 ## 0.01831564
 1 - pgamma(4, 2, 1)
 ## 0.0915782
```

[image]
>